# multiplying polynomials using linked list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, polynomials

This is my code for multiplying two polynomials using liked list.It works fine but the problem is if I multiply (3x^2+5x+3)*(4x^3+5^x+2)

I get the result as 12x^5+15x^2+6x^2+20x^4+25x^2+10x+12x^3+15x
+6.

But how can I make it so that it outputs the terms with similar exponents are added togther like 12x^5+43x^2+..

```
public class LinkedPoly{
    static String exponent="";
    Node2 head;
    Node2 current;

    LinkedPoly(){
        head=null;

    }
    public void createList(int c,int e){
        head=new Node2(c,e,head);
    }
    public static LinkedPoly multiply(LinkedPoly list1,LinkedPoly list2){
        Node2 temp1=list1.head;
        Node2 temp2=list2.head;
        Node2 temp3=temp2;
        LinkedPoly multiplyList=new LinkedPoly();

        while(temp1!=null){
            while(temp2!=null){
                multiplyList.createList((temp1.coef*temp2.coef),(temp1.exp+temp2.exp)); 
                temp2=temp2.next;
            }
            temp2=temp3;
            temp1=temp1.next;
        }

        return multiplyList;
    }
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394860

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to put the values into a map keyed on the degree of the exponent with a value indicating the coefficient. I.e.,

```
Map<Integer,Integer> exponents = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()
....
// inside your while loop
int newcoeff = temp1.coef*temp2.coef
int newexp   = temp1.exp+temp2.exp
if(exponents.containsKey(newexp))
    exponents.put(newexp, exponents.get(newexp) + newcoeff)
else 
    exponents.put(newexp,newcoeff)
```

and then convert the HashMap back to a list.

Comment: This is  the right basic idea.  To avoid having a call to `containsKey` _and_ a call to `get`, it's probably better just to call `get`, then check whether the result is null.

Comment: @DavidWallace - In this case it doesn't matter, but this is generally not a good practice on map structures that allow null values since you can't distinguish between the item being absent or null

Comment: @dfb : Thanks for the answer.But I haven't learnt about maps.So if you can guide me with another approach that would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not solving some school homework or exercise for you. In that case you shouldn't use it!

This solution does not use `Map`, but it is much slower then the one posted by @dfb.

```
/**
 * @param list will be modified (merged).
 * @return the merged list param. 
 */
public static LinkedPoly merge(LinkedPoly list) {
    Node2 temp1 = list.head;

    while (temp1 != null) {
        Node2 iter = temp1; 
        Node2 temp2 = iter.next;
        while (temp2 != null) {
            if (temp1.exp == temp2.exp) {
                temp1.coef += temp2.coef;

                //removing temp2 form the source list
                iter.next = temp2.next;
            }
            iter = iter.next;
            temp2 = iter.next;
        }
        temp1 = temp1.next;
    }

    return list;
}
```

Instead of `LinkedPoly.multiply(a, b)` just call `LinkedPoly.merge(LinkedPoly.multiply(a, b))`